# How to clean/format awk output?

Tags: macos, curl, awk, grep

Trying to grab just the latest version number which will always be behind "misc" from ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/mac/AcrobatDC/

I might be able to fix this by using "cut" but it might not stick with the next latest version if the time is x:xx.

Current code:

```
latestver=`/usr/bin/curl -s -L "ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/mac/AcrobatDC/" | /usr/bin/awk '/misc/ {print a}{a=$0}'`
    echo "Latest Version is: $latestver"
```

Output:

```
Latest Version is: drwxrwxr-x    2 ftp      ftp           142 Apr 01 11:13 1901020099
```

Expected Output:

```
Latest Version is: 1901020099
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
latestver=$(curl -s -L "ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/mac/AcrobatDC/" | awk '$NF=="misc" {print f} {f=$NF}')
echo "$latestver"
1901020099
```

How it works:

- `$NF=="misc"` tests if the last field is `misc`
- `{print f}` then prints what's in the variable `f`
- `{f=$NF}` sets `f` to last field.

Since `f` is set after the test it will always have previous value you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly and thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following(not tested since curl can't be tested).

```
latestver=$(/usr/bin/curl -s -L "ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/mac/AcrobatDC/" | /usr/bin/awk '/misc/{print $NF}')
echo "Latest Version is: $ltestver"
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply, however the output was - "Latest Version is: misc"

Comment: @DankDalf, ok, it was written as per seeing your attempt, could you please post output of your curl command and let me know then? EDIT your post  please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
$ latestver=$( wget -qO- ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/mac/AcrobatDC/ | grep 'pub/adobe/reader/mac/AcrobatDC' | sed 's/.*">\(.*\)\/<.*/\1/g' | tail -2 | head -1 )
```

Comment: Trading a single Awk invocation for a twisty maze of `grep` + `sed` + `tail` + `head` is hardly an improvement.

Comment: @tripleee, write an answer. There's always room for improvement.